# Как использовать конструкцию “i for i in” из python в ocaml

Tags: python, ocaml

У меня есть функция на питоне:

```
def foo(n, d = 0):
    if n == 0:return [[]]
    print(x for x in foo(n-1, 0))
    return [[0] + x for x in foo(n-1, 0)] + [[1] + x for x in foo(n-1, 1)]
```

На ocaml это должно выглядить как-то так

```
let foo ?(d=0) n = if n = 0 then [[]] else [[0] @ foo (n-1)] @ [[1] @ foo (n-1) ~d:1];;
```

Но у меня ошибка:

```
Error: This expression has type int list list
       but an expression was expected of type int list
       Type int list is not compatible with type int
```

Я думаю тут проблема при переводе `x for x in foo(n-1, 0)` (как-то использовать `List.iter`?), но никак не могу понять как правильно все сделать

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Питоновский фрагмент кода:

```
[0] + x for x in foo(n-1, 0)
```

на самом деле выглядит как:

```
([0] + x) for x in foo(n-1, 0)
```

а не:

```
[0] + (x for x in foo(n-1, 0))
```

Другими словами если хочется добавить `0` в начало каждого элемента сгенерированного списка. Решение этого в OCaml делается благодаря `List.map`:

```
List.map (fun x -> 0 :: x) (foo (n - 1))
```

Тк функция `foo` рекурсиваня, то необходимо ее объявить как `let rec`.

Если применить эти правки, то мы получим:

```
let rec foo ?(d=0) n =
    if n = 0 then [[]]
    else
        List.map (fun x -> 0 :: x) (foo (n-1)) @
        List.map (fun x -> 1 :: x) (foo (n-1) ~d: 1)
```

Более компактная версия кода:

```
let rec foo n =
  if n = 0 then [[]]
  else let m = foo (n - 1) in List.(map (cons 0) m @ map (cons 1) m)
```

Оригинал ответа: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57129545/how-to-use-i-for-i-in-construction-from-python-in-ocaml